# How to PeerJS over the Internet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, peerjs

in the local LAN everything is working very well, but over the internet it doesn't work.
i read a lot about WebRTC Signaling.

i use the following node.js peerjs server

whats wrong with my config?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;

var server = PeerServer({
    port: 3001,
    debug: true,
    path: '/peerjs',
    ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'utf8')
    },
    config: {'iceServers': [
    { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
  ]} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use a PeerServer that is not on your local network (=accessible to the internet). There is one provided by peer.js, which is used by default when no PeerServer URL is specified by the client.

To establish a connection, a library like socket.io can be very useful. This video gives a good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4

Comment: i had used the quite nicesample code. But how to make it work over the internet?

Comment: @HorusSirius My version is working over the internet... Check out this repo:https://github.com/codemaster138/overwire and the live demo: https://overwire.herokuapp.com

Comment: In case anyone else gets here, the above demo works with adding / notifying that users are _trying_ to connect, but the underlying WebRTC stream doesn't work across the internet generically (if the two clients are behind NATs). I'm guessing it's because there's no TURN server set up.